Databricks value is null after loading a saved df when using specific type in schema
I am facing an issue when using databricks, when I set a specific type in my schema and read a json, its values are fine, but after saving my df and loading again, the value is gone.
I have this sample code that shows this issue:
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, MapType, DoubleType, ArrayType, LongType, BooleanType
import os
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, current_date, date_sub, input_file_name, regexp_extract, split,expr, to_date, date_format,from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from delta.tables import *
import logging
import tempfile
import inspect 
import collections 
import json

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

mockschema = StructType([
    StructField("bot", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("channel", StringType(), True),
    StructField("chills", StringType(), True),
    StructField("cookies", MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True),
    StructField("geo", StructType([
        StructField("city", StringType(), True),
        StructField("country", StringType(), True),
        StructField("region", StringType(), True),
        # StructField("latitude", StringType(), True), # this works, user id is shown
        # StructField("longitude", StringType(), True) # this works, user id is shown
        StructField("latitude", DoubleType(), True),  # this does not work, user id is null
        StructField("longitude", DoubleType(), True)  # this does not work, user id is null
    ]), True),
    StructField("ip", StringType(), True),
    StructField("timestamp", LongType(), True),
    StructField("ua", StringType(), True),
    StructField("url", StringType(), True),
    StructField("user_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("vibes", StringType(), True)
])

mock_data = {
    "bot": False,
    "channel": "YES",
    "chills": "VERY_COLD",
    "cookies": {
        "1111": "aa",
        "2222": "bb",
        "3333": "cc",
        "4444": "dd",
        "5555": "ee",
        "6666": "ff", 
    },
    "geo": {
        "city": "Such City",
        "country": "AA",
        "region": "WOWW",
        "latitude": -1.924868,
        "longitude": 25.424055
    },
    "ip": "123.45.678.90",
    "timestamp": 1711711760169,
    "ua": "SOME_BROWSER_USER_AGENT",
    "url": "www.some.url.com",
    "user_id": "123456789"
}

output_format = 'delta'

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as d:
    
    spark.createDataFrame(
        [mock]
    ).write.mode("overwrite").format("json").save(d)

            
    df = spark.read.schema(mockschema).json(d)
    df = df.withColumn("date_partition", regexp_extract(input_file_name(), r'.*\/(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})\/.*', 1))
    df = df.withColumn("date_partition", date_format(to_date("date_partition", "yyyy-M-d"), "yyyy-MM-dd")) #Fortmat with leading zeros for better sorting
    df = df.withColumn("filename", expr("regexp_extract(input_file_name(), '[^/]+$', 0)"))
    display(df[['user_id', 'filename']]) # df before saving, have user id
    
    df_repartitioned = df.repartition("date_partition")
    df_repartitioned.write.format(output_format).mode("overwrite").save(f"{d}/df")
    logger.info(f"dumped df to temp folder")


    df = spark.read.format(output_format).load(f"{d}/df")
    display(df[['user_id', 'filename']]) # df after saving, missing user id when double type in geo
    


in mockschema, setting geo as doubletype makes so the saved df user_id becomes none, and setting this as string "solves" the issue.
I need to understand why this happens as I have some other codes with same issue of fields missing after saving, but couldn't track down why this schema causes an error. Does anyone ever faced something like that and can explain?
Thanks in advance <3
This "issue" is solved by using another schema types, but the issue being on "user_id" field the schema problem was in "geo", we have other schemas and couldnt track which schema interfere with another one.
I want first understand whats causing this behavior.
The value of user_id should be the same after saving than before, not having any loss of data
